# R Shiny Invalidatelater and Observe

Tags: r, shiny

I am attempting to refresh data from excel csv files as well as from webservice calls for a shiny app that i created. I understand the concept of invalidate later and `reactivevalues()`. However, there are many dataframes that rely on the initial ones created from the csv files and webservice calls and in order to update all of the downstream lists and dataframes I would have to put them all within observe blocks, make them globally defined since they are not within the server block, and prepend `values$data` to each dataframe - assuming I initialized `values <- reactivevalues()`. Is there an easier way to go about this to make sure all downstream dataframes are updated?

Comment: I guess you are on the right track and there is no shortcut. You need to put your reactive Values inside the server. You can create one `reactive()` (or `observeEvent` a button) for every stream that you are accessing. Every time the stream is refreshed (via button or timer), the corresponding `reactive` (or `reactiveVal`) is re-fetched and refreshed.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I cannot put the reactivevalues in the server since it takes about 3 min to grab the data and I don't want users to wait that long each time the page is refreshed. I would prefer not to use a button for the same reason, but rather have the data refresh every 24 hours (at night sometime).

Comment: Then that big data doesn't need to be reactive - restart you app every 24 hours, fetch the data and create the depenend outputs in the server according to that updated data?!

Comment: Are you able to explain how that would work outside of creating a script that runs the app? I am looking to perform a large data refresh within the app code base itself. I saw this example, but I can't seem to get it to work: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1690